# Determining if Chrome is in Fullscreen Mode for extension development

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension

Unsatisfied with the current extensions and workarounds to enter in a URL while full-screened in Google Chrome, I'm trying to write my own. Is there some kind of Event or Attribute I can check/use with the Chrome API to find out if the browser is in full-screen mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are some extensions out there that does Fullscreen controls.

Right now, if you want to check if Chrome is in fullscreen, you can use simple JavaScript functionality to do this:

```
var is_fullscreen = (screen.width == window.outerWidth &&
                     screen.height == window.outerHeight);
```

Note, the above must be used in a content script.

Comment: This worked better for me:


    `var is_fullscreen = (screen.width == window.outerWidth &&
                     screen.height == window.outerHeight);`

Comment: Also note that this code doesn't work in the Background Page.